# How do I send multiple recipient SMS using the Azure communication service SMS in c#

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, sms, azure-communication-services

I am developing small web application to send SMS using Azure communication service for multiple recipients. I got a following code from official microsoft page and it is working for one recipient.

```
SmsClient smsClient = new SmsClient(connectionString);

        SmsSendResult sendResult = smsClient.Send(
            from: sms.From.ToString(),
            to: sms.To.ToString(),
            message: sms.Body,
            options: new SmsSendOptions(enableDeliveryReport: true) { }
        ) ;
```

if I pass a list of recipients the "to" showing a syntax error.

**SMS.cs**

```
`public class SMS 
    {
         public SMS() { }

        public SMS(SMS sms)
        {
            if (sms == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sms));

            From = sms.From;
            To = sms.To;
            Body = sms.Body;
        }

        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string From { get; set; }
       
        public string Body { get; set; }
       
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string[] To { get; set; }
    }`
```

I modified the code like as below

```
 List<SmsSendResult> sendResult = (List<SmsSendResult>) smsClient.Send(
            from: sms.From,
            to: sms.To,
            message: sms.Body,
            options: new SmsSendOptions(enableDeliveryReport: true) { }
        ) ;
```

the error is [image]

the ACS method parameter is [image]

Can anyone please help in this?

Comment: The method wants a string input and you are sending an array of strings.  If you want to send multiple message to modem that you can combine the array using : string.Join("", string[])

Comment: Actually the method wants IEnumerable<string>. I tried to typecasting but it is not working.

Comment: No!!! exception says cannot cast string[] to string.  The low level SMS interface doesn't have a string[] method.  You are sending data to a modem which is probably USB cable and the driver for the modems only accepts string (not array).

Comment: @MuthukaniK Did you get any chance to look into this [shared example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/sms/send?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-csharp#send-a-1n-sms-message-with-options) in the documentation for sending single message to list of recipients

Comment: @MuthukaniK, Thanks for your response and glad to know your problem got resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the [sample example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/sms/send?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-csharp#send-a-1n-sms-message-with-options) on how to send sms 1:N list of recipients using azure communication service using Send or SendAsync function from the SmsClient with a list of recipient phone numbers.

**Here is the sample example:**

```
Response<IReadOnlyList<SmsSendResult>> response = smsClient.Send(
    from: "<from-phone-number>",
    to: new string[] { "<to-phone-number-1>", "<to-phone-number-2>" },
    message: "Weekly Promotion!",
    options: new SmsSendOptions(enableDeliveryReport: true) // OPTIONAL
    {
        Tag = "marketing", // custom tags
    });

IEnumerable<SmsSendResult> results = response.Value;
foreach (SmsSendResult result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Sms id: {result.MessageId}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Send Result Successful: {result.Successful}");
}
```

You need to Make these replacements in the above code:

- Replace  with an SMS-enabled phone number that's associated with your Communication Services resource.
- Replace  and  with phone numbers that you'd like to send a message to.